# C# equivalent of C++/CLI data types

Tags: c#, function, c++-cli, type-conversion

What would be C# equivalent?

```
private array<__int32>^ func()
{
}
```

Comment: `private int[] func()` ? Never programmed with C++/CLI so I'm not sure.

Comment: Be a bit careful with types like __int32.  That's a type that will *never* change size, not even on the 256-bit machine that computes your retirement fund balance some day.  Both C# and C++ use int as an alias to future-proof the languages.  If you keep it then `Int32[] func()` is appropriate.

Comment: That's not valid C++/CLI code.  In C++, `private` is not a per-member modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right type should be:

```
private int[] func()
{
}
```

or even

```
private List<int> func()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I never programmed in C++/CLI, I think these are the types you are looking for:

- Simple array: `int[]`
- Dynamically expanding array: `List<int>`